# Designer automatically re-sizes form when certain properties are set

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

I am facing an issue where a WinForms form is being automatically re-sized every time the designer is opened.

This only appears to happen with a certain setup, however it can easily be replicated with the following steps...

1. Create a new project in visual studio
2. The default form size is 300 x 300, but whatever you set it to make a note
3. Set the `FormBorderStyle` property to `FixedSingle`
4. Set the `ShowIcon` property to `false`
5. Set the `ControlBox` property to `false`
6. Save the changes
7. Close the designer
8. Re-open the designer and you will notice the form has shrunk by 4 pixels (both width and height)

The problem I have with this is that when it happens it does not resize any of the controls (i.e. the ones set with anchors), so this means I end up with controls that overlap the form edge and everything needs to be manually readjusted every time I open the designer which is a pain.

So the question is: Why is this happening, and what can I do to stop it happening?

---

I am currently using Visual Studio 2012 Professional, and John Willemse has confirmed via comments that this issue is also present in Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this using your steps. It only does it once and you can open close the designer multiple times without changes to the size. However, as soon as you change *anything* on the form, e.g. adding a control, changing the size, etc., then save and close and open again, the form will shrink by 4 pixels again. Strange behaviour indeed. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional by the way.

Comment: @JohnWillemse: Yes it is strange, and it doesn't stop there. Whilst trying to find a fix, I have noticed some other settings will allow the form to stay the same size, but the contents of the form get resized (anchored controls). I wont bloat the question by adding the process just yet. And thanks for confirming the issue in 2010

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see it, this should be a bug in any VS version.  It is caused by the ShowIcon property, the designer doesn't handle it correctly when you set it to False.  At issue is a bit of code in the Form class that looks like this:

```
       FormBorderStyle borderStyle = FormBorderStyle;
       if (!ShowIcon &&
           (borderStyle == FormBorderStyle.Sizable ||
            borderStyle == FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D ||
            borderStyle == FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle))
       {
           cp.ExStyle |= NativeMethods.WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME;
       }
```

In other words, when ShowIcon is False then it uses a *different* border style from WS_BORDER, it uses the one of a modal dialog.  Which has different borders on older Windows versions, they are fatter.  Not exactly sure what inspired this code, probably has something to do with Windows 98.

Problem is, the Size property is a *calculated* value, the Winforms designer only stores the ClientSize property.  So when ShowIcon is False then it should redo this calculation, it doesn't.

You can report the bug at connect.microsoft.com but the odds that Microsoft is going to fix it are exceedingly low so it would probably be a waste of your time.  There is a very simple workaround for it, instead of setting ShowIcon to False in the Properties window, do it in the constructor instead.  Like this:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ShowIcon = false;
    }
```

Comment: Ah yes, of course it works. Not sure how I can validate your reasons but the size calculation reason makes sense, and the solution definitely works. Wasn't expecting this to be something MS would fix anyway, wasn't even expecting to get much of a response here either, so thanks for that